# Python Classes and Inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm studying Python programming and I'm having difficulty understanding Inheritance.  My assignment is to:

1. Create a Division and Department class.
2. Create a method named “getList()” which will display a message, “The
   dept department has fullTime full-time and partTime part-time
   instructors.”
3. In the “Department” class, assign 12 as value to the fullTime
   variable, assign 27 to partTime, and “CIS” to dept. DO NOT create
   any method in the “Department” class. and
4. Create an instance (object) of the “Department” class named
   “myDept”. Use this “myDept” object to call the “getList()” method of
   “Division” class (through Inheritance).

**Here's what I have so far.**

```
    class Division():
        def __init__(self, dept, fullTime, partTime):
            self.dept = dept
            self.fullTime = fullTime
            self.partTime = partTime

        def getList(self):
            return "The (0) department has (1) full-time and (2) part-time instructors.".format(self.dept, self.fullTime, self.partTime)

    class Department(Division):

        myDept = Division(CIS247, 12, 27)
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: `an instance (object) of the “Department” class named “myDept”.` your `myDept` is an instance of `Division`. Also, it is in `Departement`, for some reason (it probably shouldn't). `call the getList() method` seems straight forward to me?

Comment: What precisely is the problem? You appear to be confusing inheritance and composition: `Department` shouldn't *contain* a `Division`; it *is* one.

Comment: My question is, am I on the write track with parts 1 and 2 in the instructions?  I'm having difficulty understanding how to assign values to the variables and then how to create the `myDept` instance to call the `getList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Division(object):
    def __init__(self,dept, fullTime, partTime):
        self.fullTime = fullTime
        self.partTime = partTime
        self.dept=dept
    def getList(self):
      return "The {0} department has {1} full-time and {2} part-time instructors.".format(self.dept, self.fullTime, self.partTime)

class Department(Division):
    pass
myDept = Department("CIS",12,37)
print myDept.getList()
```

Edited, I missed the "CIS", for string formatting you use {} not ().
Also " DO NOT create any method in the “Department” class." so removed init method.

[python classes tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: `class Division()` is an old-style object. Also, don't ever call `ParentClass.method` from a child class. Use [super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) instead! And in any event, `Department.__init__` doesn't do anything that `Division.__init__` doesn't so don't bother overriding it.

Comment: @KirkStrauser I edited the answer. What is wrong with calling ParentClass.method from the child? I have been reading Mark Lutz programming Python and he states that using super can break backwards compatibility with old style classes and has issues with multiple inheritance, what is your take on that, it is an issue I have been confused with?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, @KirkStrauser - Thank you for the input and assistance.  I want to review more on classes and inheritance so I can understand how you came up with the code in the Department class.  In the meantime, on both examples I am getting an `invalid syntax` error on `print myDept.getList()`

Comment: @CoPoPHP You're probably using Python 3. Change that to `print(myDept.getList())` instead.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `super()` is how we fix problems with multiple inheritance. :-) Also, old-style classes are so rare that you don't really need to worry about them. See [Python's super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) by Raymond Hettinger (who you can consider authoritative for this kind of stuff).

Comment: @KirkStrauser, thanks I better get another book :)